# Having troubles with start up Vue application;

Tags: windows, vue.js, webpack

My Source code is:

```
import Vue from "vue";
console.log('Vue', Vue)
```

With this packages versions:

```
"@vue/cli": "4.5.15",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.1",
"@vue/cli-service": "4.5.15",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
"@vue/component-compiler-utils": "^3.1.2",
```

But it shows me an error when i mount app.js file to html.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at hasOwn (<anonymous>)
    at t.exports (well-known-symbol.js:16:26)
    at Object.c04e (to-primitive.js:10:20)
    at a (bootstrap:79:22)
    at Object.a04b (to-property-key.js:1:19)
    at a (bootstrap:79:22)
    at Object.06cf (object-get-own-property-descriptor.js:6:21)
    at a (bootstrap:79:22)
    at Object.23e7 (export.js:2:32)
    at a (bootstrap:79:22)
```

May be it problem with ES versions or something else, idk how to google it, help pls with any proposals

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my package.json from

```
 "vuex": "^4.0.2",
 "vue-cli": "^2.9.6",
 "@vue/cli": "4.5.15",
 "vue-loader": "^16.0.0-beta.8",
 "vue-router": "^4.0.13",
 "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.1",
 "@vue/cli-service": "4.5.15",
 "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
```

to

```
"vue": "2.6.*",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.0.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.3.1",
"@vue/cli": "^5.0.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.1",
"@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.1",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
```

And app complied without this error.